# ASP.NET Server Control Type in PHP and ASP.NET MVC

Tags: php, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have created a server control in ASP.NET that generates DLL and we can use it an any another application we need. It is so helpful.

Now I want to create server control type of application in PHP and ASP.NET MVC 3.
Can you provide me some sample application or example for PHP and ASP.NET MVC 3, so that I am able to achieve my task?

Comment: More complex answer: Server controls as in ASP.NET do not exist in PHP or ASP.NET MVC, but you can create reusable components that give many of the benefits of server controls.

Answer (score 1):

Dai's simple rules for converting from ASP.NET WebForms Controls to Anything Else:

1. Extract the "model" from your control (i.e. encapsulate all of the possible input variables into a single object)
2. Analyse how variations in this model object cause the rendered output (HTML) to change.
3. Re-implement said rendered output-generation logic in your desired framework.

If I have this in WebForms:

```
public class WhateverControl : Control {
    public String SomeParameter { get; set; }
    public override void Render(HtmlTextWriter wtr) {
        wtr.WriteLine("<p>" + SomeParameter + "</p>");
    }
}
```

In PHP, like this:

```
class Model {
    // control parameters go here, e.g. visiblity, data to be displayed, form fields, etc
   public $someParameter;
}

public function renderWhatever(Model $model) {
    echo "<p>" . $model->someParameter . "</p>";
}
```

In ASP.NET MVC (using Helpers), like this:

```
public class Model {
    public String SomeParameter { get; set; }
}

public static MvcHtmlString Whatever(this HtmlHelper html, Model model) {
    return MvcHtmlString.Create("<p>" + model.SomeParameter + "</p>");
}

<%= html.Whatever( new Model() { SomeParameter = "arse" } ) %>
```

Comment: I have created a class in PHP, that contains some useful methods. Now I want to give it to my client so that he can be able to use it just like server control in asp.net instead of providing code file.
How can I compile the PHP file and provide it to my user in the form dll or may be with other  type or extension?

Comment: PHP code isn't compiled. It's distributed in source form. (There are methods to encrypt PHP source code, but it requires using a modified server which most ISPs don't provide).